# Recording the generated audio in an OpenAL based sequencer app

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, audio-recording, openal

I have a sequencer style app that plays small, pre-recorded wav files. The user can set up beats, melodies, etc. It's all built on OpenAL, which does a nice job of playing lots of samples at once and keeping the output from clipping.

I want to create a recording feature that records the outgoing audio into a file that the user can save, share, etc. It seems that recording the microphone input is easy enough, but recording the system audio after everything has been mixed together is far less trivial. Will OpenAL let me tap into the output stream and copy it to a file? Do I need to be hooking into the remoteIO audio unit and if so, does that mean dumping OpenAL and re-writing everything with Core Audio and Audio Units?

I can't seem to find much at all on this topic, and considering how many music creation apps there are I'm surprised this hasn't been hashed out somewhere. I'm hoping, if not for an explicit answer, for someone to at least point me in the right direction.

Here's what my "play sound" method looks like, in case it's helpful.

```
ALenum err = alGetError();

NSNumber * numVal = [self.soundDictionary objectForKey:soundKey];
NSUInteger bufferID = [numVal unsignedIntValue];

NSUInteger sourceID = [self nextAvailableSource];

alSourcei(sourceID, AL_BUFFER, 0);
alSourcei(sourceID, AL_BUFFER, bufferID);
alSourcef(sourceID, AL_PITCH, 1.0);
alSourcef(sourceID, AL_GAIN, .6);

err = alGetError();
if (err != 0) {
    NSLog(@"OpenAL play sound error!!");
}

alSourcePlay(sourceID);
```

Comment: There appears to be no current public API that allows tapping the output of OpenAL audio.  Best bet is to use the Audio Unit API instead, where you can tap the RemoteIO audio output.

Comment: Ugh. Alright, at least now I can stop wasting time hacking around with OpenAL and just dig in to Audio Units. Thanks for making that clear.